# Norm induced by Dot Product?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Prove, that in $[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ bounded and closed interval, the continuously differentiable functions(with complex values) on the set $C^1[a,b]$,

$$||f||=(\int_a^b |f(x)|^2 dx + \int_a^b |f'(x)|^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

is a norm induced by dot product. Write down the dot product, and prove, that it fulfills all of its conditions.

I am pretty confused in this task. How do I prove, that a norm is induced by dot product? I am not sure that I have to prove, that $||f||$ is indeed a norm. How do I begin proving, what the task really asks for?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\left< , \right> :C^1 [a,b]\times C^1 [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by $$\left< f, g\right> =\int_{[a,b]} f(u) g(u) du +\int_{[a,b]} f'(u) g'(u) du $$